# How can I use AJAX to retrieve PHP data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am a newbie at AJAX, and have been avoiding it for quite some time. I am currently working with a jQuery plugin and I need to use AJAX to communicate what data to work with (from the PHP).

Here is the jQuery code I am using:

```
$("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function () {
    $.fancybox.open([{
        href: '1_b.jpg',
        title: 'My title'
    }, {
        href: '2_b.jpg',
        title: '2nd title'
    }, {
        href: '3_b.jpg'
    }], {
        helpers: {
            thumbs: {
                width: 75,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How can I use AJAX to retrieve the PHP data to enter the href and title. Any information or tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `ajax()` demonstrates several examples, here is another basic one:

*javascript*

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  dataType:'json',
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  if (msg.err == true) {
     alert('Error: '+msg.msg);
     return;
  }
  alert("A winner is: '+msg.name);
});
```

*php*

```
    <?php

        $response = array(
            'err'=>false,
            'msg'=>''
        );
        $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
        $location= isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : false;

        if (!$name) {
            $response['err'] = true;
            $response['msg'] = 'Invalid name';
            die(json_encode($response));
        }

        $response['name'] = $name;
        if ($location)
            $response['name'] .= ' from '.$location;
        die(json_encode($response));
 ?>
```

As you've noticed, most developers encourage one another to check documentation first, and indeed a Google query "ajax tutorial" would have been quite fruitful! :)

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.ajax()` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- PHP `json_encode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
- More ajax tutorials - http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/
- AJAX explained - http://www.zdnet.com/blog/service-oriented/ajax-explained/8473

Comment: Is it possible to put data into an array and allow Ajax to take it and place it in javascript?

Comment: @Jamie -- yes, that is what `json_encode` does. Please carefully consider the sample code, and do check out those documentation pages! :)

Answer (score 1):

I was in the exact same situation as you just yesterday.  There are plenty of good Ajax tutorials around online, but none seem to give the most basic example possible. Here is what I did to learn.

Make sure you have jquery.js in the same folder as this html file. I named mine test.php.

This file makes a very simple POST ajax call to the file script.php, it also sends one variable called testCheck with the value of true.  After the data is returned the callback function runs which populates the DIV called #test with the response given by AJAX.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
#test {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: gray;
}
</style>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#test").click(function() {
    $.post("script.php", {testCheck: true}, function(data) {
      $('#test').html(data);
    });     
});   
});
</script>

<body>
  <div id="test">TEST DIV</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script.php file which has the php logic. If you put both files along with the jquery.js file into the same directory and run it on an Apache server it should work fine.

```
<?php


$testCheck = $_POST['testCheck'];

if($testCheck)
{
    echo "It is true!";
}
else
{
    echo "It is false!";
}

?>
```